# Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got about). Pass the callable instead

Tags: django

From `django.conf.urls` import url

```
urlpatterns =  [
    'chat.views',
    url(r'^$', 'about'),

     url(r'^new/$', 'new_room'),
    url(r'^(?P<label>[\w-]{,50})/$', 'chat_room'),
]
```

can any one please help me

Comment: your first value in `urlpatterns` is only string, it should be a url-pattern.

Comment: can you please help me with correct code as I am new with python

Comment: for start comment the first value `'chat.views'` and check again

Comment: Still getting the same error after commenting :(

Comment: then import `new_room`, `char_room` and `about` view to urls.py and call them like ``url(r'^new/$', new_room)``.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
from chat import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns =  [
    url(r'^$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.new_room, name='new_room'),
    url(r'^(?P<label>[\w-]{,50})/$', views.chat_room, name='chat_room'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use strings in the view arguments. Try this instead:

```
from chat.views import about, new_room, chat_room
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns =  [
    url(r'^$', about),
    url(r'^new/$', new_room),
    url(r'^(?P<label>[\w-]{,50})/$', chat_room),
]
```